# How is advised to use the contentResolver's delete method to be injection safe?

Tags: android, sql-injection, android-contentresolver, android-sdk-2.1

You can delete with content resolver by URI or by passing some parameters to the where parameter.

How do you make the parameters to be SQL Injection Safe?
Is it possible to use Prepared Statements with ContentResolver?

```
act.getContentResolver().delete(myuriwithid,null,null);

act.getContentResolver().delete(mybaseuri," name = '"+this.name"'",null);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use positional parameters.

```
public final int delete (Uri url, String where, String[] selectionArgs)
```

e.g.

```
ContentResolver cr = ...;
String where = "nameid=?";
String[] args = new String[] { "george" };
cr.delete( Stuff.CONTENT_URI, where, args );
```

Comment: I don't know. If you don't trust it, you can use SQLiteDatabase.execSQL( "delete .." ) and harden the query yourself.

Comment: By my tests it *seems* to be SQL injection safe, but I can't see it documented anywhere.

Comment: I just found some useful info, look for "SQL injection" in this page: https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html